# How to open the Tethering settings in an Honor device

Tags: android, tethering

I use this code to open the Android tethering settings screen to allow the user to enable it or to disable it. It works well for almost all devices:

```
Intent oIntent = new Intent("android.settings.TETHER_SETTINGS");                
oIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(oIntent);
```

For **Honor** devices I get the error "**No activity found to handle Intent**"

Does anyone know how to open the Tethering settings in an Honor device?